# Asterisk : how to connect my PC with Asterisk to the phone line?

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I am completely new with Asterisk. I have installed Asterisk on my PC. Now, I want to connect my PC to the phone line. How can I do ?

To be more accurate :

1. how can I do if I use an internet box connected to internet via cable or fiber ?
2. how can I do if I want to connect directly to a 'classic phone line' (FXO/FXS port)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy an analog card like this one from Digium:

http://www.digium.com/en/products/telephony-cards/analog/4-port

(I assume you have a standard analog line.  You can also buy ISDN cards).

Install the card on your PC then you can use the PSTN AND your SIP provider as required.  you can setup a dialling plan to cater for both.  eg dial 9 prefix for PSTN.

Comment: Thanks. I have a laptop ; is it possible to find analog cards but to be connected in USB for example ? What do you mean by "you can setup a dialling plan to cater for both. eg dial 9 prefix for PSTN." ? Thanks.

Comment: What model of PC would you recommend to have a small/compact/low electricity consumption Asterisk server ? Which telephony analog card to be used with it ? Thanks.